# Trigonometric Manipulations

Tags: trigonometry

> a) Express $\tan( \theta_1+\theta_2 + \theta_3 + \theta_4)$ in terms of $t_i$ where $t_1 = \tan  \theta_1$ etc.
>
> b) Given that $\tan \theta_1, \  \tan \theta_2, \ \tan \theta_3,$ and $\tan \theta_4$ are roots of the equation
>   $$at^4 + bt^3 + ct^2 + dt + e = 0 \qquad (\text{where } a \ne 0)$$
>   Find an expression in terms of $a, b, c, d , e$ for $\tan (\theta_1  + \theta_2 + \theta_3 +  \theta_4)$
>
> c) The 4 real numbers $\theta_1, \  \theta_2, \  \theta_3, \ \theta_4$ lie in the range $0 \leq \theta_i \leq 2\pi$ and satisfy the equation
>   $$p\cos2\theta + \cos(\theta - \alpha) + p = 0$$
>   where $p$ and $\alpha$ are independent of $\theta$. Show that $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 + \theta_4 = n\pi$ for some integer $n$

*I have been able to complete part a and b, part b leads to $$\frac{d-b}{a+e-c}$$

(although correct me if that is wrong)

In relation to part c, I have simplified the expression to;

$$\tan \theta = \frac{2p\cos \theta + \cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}$$

My problem is in getting from here to the final result.

Comment: So what you're trying to show is that the tangent of the sum of all four is $0$. That's the same as showing that $d-b=0$ and $a-c+e\ne0$. $\qquad$

Comment: I agree with your answer to part (b). $\qquad$

Comment: Exactly, I tried to substitute my expression for $\tan \theta$ in part c to show $d-b = 0$ but I was unable to simplify it and reach the required result

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$p\cos2\theta+\cos(\theta-\alpha)+p=0$$ becomes, after some manipulation, the equation $$2p\cos\theta+\cos\alpha+t\sin\alpha=0,$$ where $t=\tan\theta$

Writing $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ and squaring reduces this to a quartic polynomial in $t$, namely 
$$t^4\sin^2\alpha+t^3\sin2\alpha+t^2+t\sin2\alpha-4p^2=0$$

Comparing this with the results from previous parts, we see that $$\tan(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3+\theta_4)=0\Rightarrow \theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3+\theta_4=n\pi$$